# Web3js ethereum app function returns undefined

Tags: solidity, web3js

The code returns undefined. When I check the testrpc command response the transaction confirmation can be seen from the deploy code.

```
contract.deploy({
    data: crJSON.bytecode,
    arguments: ['lol']
})
.send({
    from: acc,
    gas: 1500000,
    gasPrice: '300000'
});

contract.methods.createPatient(12112333).send({from: acc},function(error, result){
    console.log(result)
 });

contract.methods.updatePatient(12112333,"aa",1,2,"abb").send({from: acc}, function(error, result){
   console.log(result)

});

contract.methods.getbirth(123112333).call({from: acc},function(error, result){
    console.log(toString(result))
});
```

The calls are not occuring one by one I think. Also how do I get the return value of `getbirth` function?

Answer (score 1):

Web3js v1.0 only support asynchronous calls and transactions. As you say the transaction seems not to be executing in the expected order. For asynchronous function you have to force them to execute in order using callbacks, promises or async/await.

Using promises it should look something like this:

```
var instance;
contract.deploy({
    data: crJSON.bytecode,
    arguments: ['lol']
})
.send({
    from: acc,
    gas: 1500000,
    gasPrice: '300000'
})
.then(function(newInstance) {
    instance = newInstance;
    return instance.methods.createPatient(12112333)
        .send({from: acc});
})
.then(function() {
    return instance.methods.updatePatient(12112333,"aa",1,2,"abb")
        .send({from: acc});
})
.then(function() {
    return instance.methods.getbirth(123112333).call({from: acc});
})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```